# Why governments are against "producing" people in artificial wombs?

Tags: economy, government, policy

Many countries and regions have demographic problems, including all of Eastern Europe, Germany, Russia, and Japan. The reason - low birthrates and/or emigration to more developed countries.

So countries attract immigrants to fix the demographic problem or boost demographics by introducing family-friendly policies.

But not all countries are attractive destination points for immigrants. Compare Germany and the Baltic states, for example. There is a huge gap in GDP and salaries between them.

Also, sources of immigrants are not endless because after 2050 the world human population is projected to start shrinking because [the fertility rate will drop below 2.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_fertility_rate) (in 2019 it was 2.4).

This will cause problems:

1. Not all countries will get the needed amount of immigrants (richer countries will attract more than developing countries)
2. The world human population will start shrinking after 2050
3. Problems with integrating immigrants into the main culture of a country

So my question is: **why aren't governments investing in artificial wombs to produce new people/citizens, as described in "[Brave New World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brave_New_World)"**? This would allow governments to:

1. Reduce expenditure on family friendly policies (schools, for example)
2. Infinite source of new people to gain taxes from in future
3. No problems with integrating them in main culture (all this will be done in orphanages)
4. You can shape new people as you want to better control them, for example

Comment: [They](https://www.nature.com/articles/546045a) [are](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms15112) investing in the science of artificial wombs.

Comment: Politics Stack Exchange is not a good forum for brainstorming novel ideas to political problems. You might want to pitch this idea and its ethical and sociopolitical implications in a more discussion-oriented community.